# Thinking Sphinx Facets on associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

Is there anyway of defining facet on an associated model's column which is of type int?Does sphinx convert all fields defined as facets to strings if they are of an associated models columns?

I am trying to define a column of my child table as an facet.After
rebuilding when I do Model1.facets i get this error.

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....

  has_many :communities, :through => :model2

  ...

  define indexes

     ...

     indexes model2.community_id, :as => :community_id, :facet => :true

     ...

  end

end
```

model 1 - Current model
model 2 - join model using :through

```
Model1.facets

NoMethodError: undefined method `to_crc32' for 9:Fixnum
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/facet.rb:99:in `translate'
        from (irb):3:in `detect'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/facet.rb:98:in `each'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/facet.rb:98:in `detect'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/facet.rb:98:in `translate'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/facet.rb:75:in `value'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/facet_search.rb:114:in `add_from_results'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:219:in `each_with_groupby_and_count'
        from (irb):3:in `each_with_index'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:218:in `each'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:218:in `each_with_index'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:218:in `each_with_groupby_and_count'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/facet_search.rb:113:in `add_from_results'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/facet_search.rb:49:in `populate'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/facet_search.rb:47:in `each'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/facet_search.rb:47:in `populate'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/facet_search.rb:13:in `initialize'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/search_methods.rb:422:in `new'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/
lib/thinking_sphinx/search_methods.rb:422:in `facets'
        from (irb):3>>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using integers for facets, then they should be defined as attributes:

```
has model2.community_id, :as => :community_id, :facet => :true
```

The `indexes` method is for fields - which are the textual data you want people to be able to search for. I'm guessing the people who use your site won't be entering in the community id into the search field. Leave a comment if that's not the case, and I'll expand on how you can have the `community_id` as both a field and an attribute.